# How to build SQL query with two left joins using django ORM

Tags: django, orm, left-join

I need to build an MySQL query and I want to try with django ORM first and then use raw as last resort.

I found documentation on single JOIN or JOINs between two tables but there is no examples or at least a simple (beginner wise) explanation of JOINs between three tables

Content of models.py is

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Threads(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField("date published")
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Posts(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField("date published")
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Relations(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Threads, related_name = "%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related")
    post = models.ForeignKey(Posts, related_name = "%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related")
```

and this is SQL query in raw that I am trying to build

```
SELECT forum_threads.id AS t_id, forum_threads.name AS t_name, forum_threads.slug AS t_slug, forum_posts.*
FROM forum_threads
LEFT JOIN forum_relations ON forum_threads.id=forum_relations.thread_id
LEFT JOIN forum_posts ON forum_relations.post_id=forum_posts.id
WHERE forum_threads.slug="<slug_name>"
GROUP BY forum_threads.id
```

"forum" is my app name

Now I don't know if I need to tweak/change my Models and if, how. Note that I can change my models no important data whatsoever.

**EDIT**

Thank you for all your answers!

Ok I played a bit with various examples until i managed to produce someting. I got it like this:

```
thread = Threads.objects.filter(slug = slug)

posts = Posts.objects.filter(forum_relations_related__thread = thread[0].id)
```

first query is to retrieve id of thread from slug and second one returns all post related to thread on that thread id.

I'll try and play around with a M2M part since I have at least one working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a [M2M](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#many-to-one-relationships) relation, you can use [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) if need be.

You could then get a thread by slug

```
thread = Threads.objects.get(slug=slug_name)
```

then you can access the posts related to a thread via

```
thread.posts_set.all()
```

Comment: OK. tried this way and it is also working, instead of **thread.posts_set.all()** I used **thread.posts.all()**.

Thanks for help.